# Click the One Button Multiple times to change the text multi time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make one `button 3-4 times` clickable to change content. Same to this button: [Go to this page ->](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp)

[image]

But I am able to make this button clickable only once.

Comment: You could check for the current text on the button and handle what should happen next. Or you could use a counter to keep track of the events.

Comment: @Bqardi can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: Something like `if (btn.textContent === "Click Me") {btn.textContent = "Something else"}`. You should share some code to show what you have tried so we can give a more specific answer to your problem.

Comment: @Bqardi only one active then another two hide:- `https://codepen.io/vishal-jenny/pen/QWxLjGE`

Comment: Instead of linking to a codepen, you should post the code in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already added the elements in an array, so a counter is the way to proceed from here:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("box1")
var b = document.getElementById("box2")
var c = document.getElementById("box3")

var multy = [a,b,c];
var index = 0; // the counter

one(); // initialize the first render

function one(){
  if (index >= multy.length) return; // bail if we've reached the last box

  a.style.display = "none";
  b.style.display = "none";
  c.style.display = "none";

  multy[index].style.display = "inline-block";
  index++;
}
```